# Prove that $3^{2^n}=o(2^{3^n})$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm not sure if this method is valid so I'd like some feedback.

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}(3^{2^n})}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}(2^{3^n})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n3^{2^n}}{3^n2^{3^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}=L\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n$$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n=0$ so $L=L\cdot0\implies L=0$.

Comment: You have some errors in your computation (when you tried to take derivatives), so it doesn't work on its face.  In addition, to use this method, you first would need to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}$ exists.

Comment: a. The calculation supposed to bring you that $L=\infty$

Comment: b. You can take the n power outside and get $({3^2}/{2^3})^n$

Comment: @friedvir Not true.  You seem to have mistaken, for instance, $3^{2^n}$ with $3^{2n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not presuppose the limit exists. Instead note $$\ln\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}=2^n\ln 3-3^n\ln 2=O(2^n)-O(3^n)=-O(3^n)\\\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}=-\infty\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}=\exp-\infty=0.$$